# Obscure issue with string formatting from SQLite database

Tags: android, string-formatting

I appreciate there's a lot of helpful stack questions and answers to my question but I'm running into problems I've not had in the past.

**The Problem:**

I am using a cursor to populate textviews in rows on a view (without using listview - that's crazy I know). I am trying to format the string value(s) taken from from the database column `STUDENT_POINTS` that are put into a textview `tpoints`. Here is the code I am using:

```
public void bindView(View v, final Context context, Cursor c) {
        final int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Students.STUDENT_ID));
        final String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Students.STUDENT_NAME));
        final String age = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Students.STUDENT_AGE));
        final String points = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Students.STUDENT_POINTS));
        final String teachernote = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Students.TEACHERNOTE));
        final byte[] image = c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(Students.IMAGE));
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                iv.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0,image.length));
            }
        }

        TextView tname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tname.setText(name);
        TextView tage = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.age);
        tage.setText(age);
        TextView tpoints = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.points);
        tpoints.setText(String.format(points, "%1$,.2f"));

        final StudentsConnector sqlCon = new StudentsConnector(context);
```

The rest of `bindView` is for buttons so I have not included it here. The problem is with the line:

```
tpoints.setText(String.format(points, "%1$,.2f"));
```

I'm intending to have commas to separate out large numbers but this does nothing! If anybody has the time could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a sample of what Students.STUDENT_POINTS contains?

Comment: It contains numbers saved as a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your two parameters backwards-- you should have the format string followed by the data string:  String.format("%1$,.2f", points );

This formatted nicely for me with this little snippet in my code:

```
    double points = 56789.45f;
    String boogie = String.format("%1$,.2f", points );
```

and it generated a number 56,789.45
But bigger numbers don't work well due to precision in the formater.  You may want to split the mantissa off of their, format them separately and combine them.

Comment: Thanks for the response, HalR. I've have tried it with the parameters reversed and it results in a force close. Perhaps converting the string to a double first might work? - I'm going to give that a go and let you know how I get on. If this doesn't work, I might have to try saving my database value as an integer/double.

Comment: It seemed to be very finicky for me.  Like a number 32343.434 would force close for me too.  I really think that if you broke it into two parts, it would format more easily.  I'll edit my post with my suggestion

Comment: I haven't had any success :/ Thanks for your answer, it of course works in most cases but I suspect I'm having trouble because of my setup in general. I'll tick it off as this would suit most cases if people were to come across this question.